# What is the correct way to unit test MvxCommand?

Tags: mvvmcross

I've reached the hair pulling out stage on this one. I'm trying to unit test that my command is being dispatched when invoked. Firstly the command works perfectly well in the app, it's just the test that's failing.

I am following the pattern used in the n+1 days of mvvm cross and have examined the recommended git examples mentions in other posts on unit test (Greg Shackles code camp etc). I am using Mvvm cross 4 though this issue also happened in 3.

So my command looks like this

```
private MvxCommand<IStation> itemSelectedCommand;

public System.Windows.Input.ICommand ItemSelectedCommand
{
    get
    {
        itemSelectedCommand = itemSelectedCommand ?? new MvxCommand<IStation>(DoSelectItem);
        return itemSelectedCommand;
    }
}
```

I have a mock dispatcher that looks like this (from the code camp samples) an that simply logs calls

```
    public class MockViewDispatcher : MvxMainThreadDispatcher, IMvxViewDispatcher
    {
        public IList<MvxViewModelRequest> ShowViewModelRequests = new List<MvxViewModelRequest>();
        public IList<MvxClosePresentationHint> CloseRequests = new List<MvxClosePresentationHint>();

        public bool ShowViewModel(MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {
            ShowViewModelRequests.Add(request);

            return true;
        }

        public bool ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)
        {
            if (hint is MvxClosePresentationHint)
                CloseRequests.Add((MvxClosePresentationHint)hint);

            return true;
        }

        public bool RequestMainThreadAction(Action action)
        {
            action();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

My unit test is as follows

```
public class ReproduceProblemTests2 : MvxIoCSupportingTest
{
    protected MockViewDispatcher Dispatcher { get; private set; }
    protected IMvxMessenger Messenger { get; private set; }

    public ReproduceProblemTests2()
    {
        base.Setup();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        MvxSingleton.ClearAllSingletons();
        ClearAll();

        Dispatcher = new MockViewDispatcher();
        Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxMainThreadDispatcher>(Dispatcher);
        Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxViewDispatcher>(Dispatcher);

        Messenger = new MvxMessengerHub();

        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxStringToTypeParser>(new MvxStringToTypeParser());
    }

    [Test]
    public void AllStationsViewModel_WhenAnItemIsSelected_ShouldExecuteCommand()
    {
        var item = new Mock<IStation>().Object;
        var service = new Mock<IStationService>();
        var sut = new AllStationsViewModel(service.Object);
        sut.ItemSelectedCommand.Execute(item);
        Dispatcher.ShowViewModelRequests.Any().Should().BeTrue();
    }
}
```

The test always fails and the dispatcher is never invoke. So I guess my wiring is wrong, but I can't see where. I am using Nunit 2.6.4 and the test fail in both the VS runner and crunch so it isn't test runner specific.

Anyone got an idea what type of idiot i'm being?

Comment: I'm not sure where this is failing. Is `DoSelectItem` called at all? Is `[SetUp]` in your class called at all. One thing I notice is that your ctor calls `base.Setup` rather than `Setup` which is a bit confusing (to me at least).